# How to split a string using the period/dot/decimal point '.' as a delimiter in R

Tags: r, string, split

I have a list of strings that end with a decimal followed by 3 digits, eg '07:02.334'. I need to extract those last three digits and thought that some form of split would work but everything I try fails, for instance:

```
> s <- '07:02.334'
> s
> str_split(s, '.')
[[1]]
 [1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

I've tried embedding the string s in a list, escaping the period "." and using whatever string splitters I've found while searching but none work.

I can use the below but I will need to do a split on other data later.

```
> file_ext(s)
[1] "334"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to escape (`\\.`) or use `fixed = TRUE` as `.` is a metacharacter in regex and it can match any character

```
strsplit(s, '.', fixed = TRUE)[[1]][2]
[1] "334"
```

According to `?strsplit`

> split - character vector (or object which can be coerced to such) containing regular expression(s) (unless fixed = TRUE) to use for splitting. If empty matches occur, in particular if split has length 0, x is split into single characters. If split has length greater than 1, it is re-cycled along x.

Also, as `strsplit`, returns a `list`, extract the list with `[[` and get the second element (`[2]`)

---

Or wrap with `fixed` in `str_split`

```
library(stringr)
str_split(s, fixed('.'))[[1]][2]
[1] "334"
```

---

We can also get the output with `trimws`

```
trimws(s, whitespace = ".*\\.")
[1] "334"
```

Or with `sub`

```
sub(".*\\.", "", s)
[1] "334"
```

Comment: Ahhh, I shall keep your methods for future use.